# How to change directories recursively in huge files

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync, mv

I tried to copy data between two huge NFS folders. I copied all the data, but I noticed that by mistake I made duplicate directories only in the 6th depth.

For example, instead of copying:

```
/mnt/nfs1/a/b/c/d/e/
/mnt/nfs1/1/2/3/4/5/
/mnt/nfs1/q/w/e/r/y/
```

to

```
/mnt/nfs2/a/b/c/d/e/
/mnt/nfs2/1/2/3/4/5/
/mnt/nfs2/q/w/e/r/y/
```

I copied it to:

```
/mnt/nfs2/a/b/c/d/d/e/
/mnt/nfs2/1/2/3/4/4/5/
/mnt/nfs2/q/w/e/r/r/y/
```

What is the fastest and most reliable way to correct the paths for the folders?

P.S. again its huge directories (with 10K+ directories).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/601878/rsync-delete-files-from-target-if-not-existing-in-source

Comment: @mashuptwice but it will copy all the files again, right? i dont want to recopy all the files (the NFS folders are huge, and it takes for ever to copy). I already have the data, i just want to change the folder path